# Adding animation Duration Value in a textbox

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, animation, textbox

I have a double animation I know I can set the duration using `:Duration="00:00:30"` for example but I would be able to write in a `Textbox` the duration value when the file is running right before start the animation.

Basically what I need is `Duration=" Time written within the TextBox"`

This is what I tried

```
Public Sub Set_Laptime(ByVal sender, ByVal KeyUpEventArgs, ByVal e)
    Dim ts As TimeSpan
    Dim LapTime As Duration
    ts = (TextBox1.Text)
    LapTime = New Duration(ts)
End Sub
```

Comment: sorry I wanted to say that I would like to be able to write in a textbox the duration......

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, yes. You just need to handle [KeyUp event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.keyup.aspx)
for example if you want to begin your animation when duration is typed and Return is pressed:

```
void textBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyUpEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key==key.return)
    {
        TimeSpan ts=TimeSpan.Parse(textBox.Text);
        Duration dur=new Duration(ts);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
VB convertion (by [this site](http://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/)):

```
Private Sub textBox_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyUpEventArgs)
    If (e.Key = key.return) Then
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(textBox.Text)
        Dim dur As Duration = New Duration(ts)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work:                                  Public Sub Set_Laptime(ByVal sender, ByVal KeyUpEventArgs)
        Dim ts As TimeSpan
        Dim LapTime As Duration
        ts = (TextBox1.Text)
        LapTime = New Duration(ts)
    End Sub

Comment: I'm not familiar with VB, but I think you did not call the method `tryParse(textBox.Text);`

Comment: @Ron Your TryParse signature is wrong, it should be `TimeSpan.TryParse(textBox.Text, out ts)`

Comment: @MarkHall you are right; thanks for mentioning this. It was supposed to be just `Parse`.

Comment: tried this:     Private Sub textBox_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyUpEvebtArguments)
        If (e.Key = Key.Return) Then
            Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(TextBox.text, out ts)
            Dim dur As Duration = New Duration(ts)
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: @Ste I am sorry, the out ts part of the TimeSpan is for C# just omit the out it should work though it will be in minutes

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you just create a TimeSpan from a string it defaults to `Days`. If you use [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) you can then use the [`TimeSpan.FromSeconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.fromseconds%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method to create your duration.  See if this works for you.

```
Public Sub Set_Laptime(ByVal sender, ByVal KeyUpEventArgs, ByVal e)
    Dim seconds As Double
    Dim ts As TimeSpan
    Dim LapTime As Duration
    If Double.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, seconds) Then
        ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)
        LapTime = New Duration(ts)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry -Please Try Again")
        TextBox1.Text = "0"
    End If
    e.Handled = True
End Sub
```

---

Added code to show a Dependecy Property using OP's code from earlier question.

First of all change your DoubleAnimations in your Xaml to this:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="MyPathAnimation">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse1"
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Left)"
                          PathGeometry="{DynamicResource Daytona}"
                          Duration="{Binding Path=getLapTime}" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Source="X" FillBehavior="Stop" />
    <DoubleAnimationUsingPath Storyboard.TargetName="Ellipse1"
                          Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)"
                          PathGeometry="{StaticResource Daytona}"
                          Duration="{Binding Path=getLapTime}" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Source="Y" FillBehavior="Stop" />
</Storyboard>
```

Then change your Code behind in your usercontrol to this:

```
Imports System.Windows.Media.Animation

Public Class UserControl1



    Public Sub runPathAnimation()
        Dim sb As Storyboard = CType(FindResource("MyPathAnimation"), Storyboard)
        sb.Begin()
    End Sub

    Shared myDependencyProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("getLapTime", GetType(Duration), GetType(UserControl1))
    Public Property getLapTime As Duration
        Get
            Return CType(GetValue(myDependencyProperty), Duration)
        End Get
        Set(value As Duration)
            SetValue(myDependencyProperty, value)
        End Set
    End Property


    Private Sub set_Laptime_KeyUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs)
        Dim seconds As Double
        Dim ts As TimeSpan
        If Double.TryParse(set_Laptime.Text, seconds) Then
            ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds)
            getLapTime = New Duration(ts)
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Entry -Please Try Again")
            set_Laptime.Text = "0"
        End If
        e.Handled = True

    End Sub

'Alternate input method to allow inputting hours, minutes and seconds

    Private Sub set_Laptime_KeyUp(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs)
        If e.Key = Key.Enter Then
            Dim seconds As Integer
            Dim hours As Integer
            Dim minutes As Integer
            Dim split As String() = New String() {":"}
            Dim input As String() = set_Laptime.Text.Split(split, StringSplitOptions.None)
            Dim ts As TimeSpan
            If input.Length > 0 Then Integer.TryParse(input(0), hours)
            If input.Length > 1 Then Integer.TryParse(input(1), minutes)
            If input.Length > 2 Then Integer.TryParse(input(2), seconds)
            ts = New TimeSpan(hours, minutes, seconds)
            getLapTime = New Duration(ts)

            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        Me.DataContext = Me 'Very important will not work if not assigned
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ok I tried this last code but it doesn't work. The duration depends always on what is set on the XAML, i have my textbox within the xaml track window , should i do something about that?

Comment: Also I think my time format for the Animation is 00:00:00 which means hour:min:sec

Comment: That is well and good, but do you expect your users to enter it as 00:00:00. You are also going to need a dependencyProperty to do what you want, I am looking into that now

Comment: yes I would like to put the duration in the TextBox1 00:00:00, I have add this line to the code above: TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", Math.Floor(ts.TotalHours), ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds)

Comment: @Ste what is it doing? this is working using the Demo code from your earlier questions.

Comment: @Ste make sure you set the DataContext in the Constructor. i.e. `Me.DataContext = Me`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21588/discussion-between-mark-hall-and-ste)